# UIViewController viewWillAppear called after its own viewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

App architecture as follows:

```
-- UINavigationController 
    -- UIViewController (rootViewController)
        -- UITabBarController
            -- ChildViewController
```

When a user takes an action within `ChildViewController`, I push a `NewViewController` onto the top-most `UINavigationController` so that it shows above everything else in the app. This all works great.

However, when this `NewViewController` is pushed to `UINavigationController`, the `ChildViewController` instantly fires its viewWillDisappear AND its viewWillAppear methods. This is the order of events:

```
NewViewController: viewDidLoad
NewViewController: viewWillAppear
ChildViewController: viewWillDisappear
ChildViewController: viewWillAppear
ChildViewController: viewDidAppear
ChildViewController: viewWillDisappear
NewViewController: viewDidAppear
```

Any idea why viewWillAppear is being called on `ChildViewController` when it is technically disappearing? Any ideas to prevent/resolve this would be helpful. Thanks!